# Ninja Kingdom Asking to update my flash but it's updated?

Tags: 13.10, flash, facebook

https://apps.facebook.com/ninjakingdom/?fb_source=canvas_bookmark

So is there a workaround to this? (on ubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 2):

Adobe has long [given up on releasing new versions](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/02/adobe-and-google-partnering-for-flash-player-on-linux.html) of Flash for Linux. 11.2 will continue to receive security fixes, but no more new features.

If Ninja Kingdom needs a newer version of Flash, which seems to be the case, currently your only option is to use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) with its integrated Flash player.